# Use an Imagebutton to return a calculation

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I begin with android programming.

I'ld like to use an imagebutton to return in a Textview the result of a calculation.

In my xml file named "content_main.xml, I declared

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgcalc"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_action_description"
    android:elevation="24dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_action" />
```

And in my MainActivity.java I have

```
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    ImageButton imgbutton =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgcalc);
    imgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sommesaisie = Double.parseDouble(txproteines.getText().toString()) + Double.parseDouble(txcendres.getText().toString()) + Double.parseDouble(txfibres.getText().toString()) + Double.parseDouble(txhumidite.getText().toString()) + Double.parseDouble(txmg.getText().toString());
            resultatbrut = 100 - sommesaisie;
            resultatsec = (resultatbrut * 100) / (100 - Double.parseDouble(txhumidite.getText().toString()));

            //if (sommesaisie > 100){
            //txglucides.setText("###");
            //txtresult.setText("ERREUR :");
            //} else {
                txglucides.setText("xxx");
            //}
        }
    });
```

Of course, the real return would be the result of the calculation : "resultatbrut". But for testing, I just try to return "xxx".
The problem I have is that nothing is returned...

Could you please help me ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: please share the xml for Textview (``txglucides ``) and how are you getting its reference in MainActivity ?

Comment: share your complete code

Comment: Of course. The txglucides is
<code><TextView
            android:id="@+id/txglucides"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="-/-"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" /></code>

Comment: sorry but it's the 1st time I post here so I didn't find how to format in an anwser